# Capistrano 3 simple update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3

I have a Rails application which I deployed to a remote server with git and Capistrano 3. It works fine.

Sometimes after I change some files (in app/views, for example), I want to upload those changes to the current release without running the full cycle of deploy process.

I need one command to upload changed files (files in the last commit in git) to the current release directory on the remote server.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Why not go through the full deploy cycle?

Comment: it is too slow. I am debugging my site on server by making many many small changes to views. I am testing how my site looks by another tool which can access my site only from internet but cannot access my local version. Why should I create a new release, and other stuff, and then restart rails app.

Comment: Did you find a solution to that? I need to do the same thing... :(

Answer (score 0):

**Improve Performance with Remote Cache**

The way Capistrano works, it will create a new clone/export of your repository on every deploy. That can be slow, so there’s an option to add some extra commands to our deploy.rb recipe to speed things up. Add the following to the section of your `deploy.rb` where you describe your scm settings: `set :deploy_via, :remote_cache`

This command makes Capistrano do a single clone/checkout of your repository on your server the first time, then do an `svn up or git pull` on every deploy instead of doing an entire clone/export. If you deploy often, you’ll notice that this speeds up your deployments significantly.

Hope this help you what you are looking for!!!

For more detail check out this link. [deploy-with-capistrano](http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/deployments/deploy-with-capistrano.html)

Comment: what if I just want to copy changed files from git, without creating a new release and not executing all other stuff capistrano does during deploy ?